# Boot from new SSD drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd

I just installed a new 1TB SSD drive on an older Dell XPS 8700.

When I boot up, the drive does not appear. But going in to Disk Management, I see it, and I can intialize it.

But what I'd like to do is make the new drive bootable. I created a USB drive with a bootable version of Windows that came with the system (Windows 8.1). How do I format the drive as a bootable drive and make it the bootable disk?

I assume the first step is to initialize the drive, but Windows Disk Management wants to give it the letter K:, and I'd really prefer C:.

Comment: initialize it, drive letter does not matter, Install windows on the SSD, boot from the install usb and follow the prompts to install on the SSD. Once windows 8.1 is installed it will be bootable and C drive. Disconnect the old drive before booting from usb and installing W8

Comment: @Moab: Thanks. I've initialized it. How do I boot from the install USB?

Comment: @Moab: And is it necessary to disconnect the old driver? I'd like to have access to the data on it.

Comment: Only while installing to the SSD, connect it back after windows is installed.

Comment: Plug the usb in and reboot, depending on the make of pc what key to hit when you see the bios splash page to get a boot menu, then select the usb to boot from. It should be F12 on a dell to get a boot menu.